# pgpool run and only log one line

Tags: vagrant, heartbeat, watchdog, postgresql

I am using pgpool and when I run:

```
sudo pgpool -f pgpool.conf -F pcp.conf -n
```

It just log one line and keep waitting.... :

```
2014-10-09 13:27:42 LOG:   pid 28626: wd_chk_setuid: ifup[/sbin/ifconfig] doesn't have setuid bit
```

I installed the pgpool-II-3.3.4 on Ubuntu-14.04 using Vagrant VM.

#### Watchdog and hearbeat configuration in my pgpool.conf:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WATCHDOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Enabling -

use_watchdog = on
                                    # Activates watchdog
                                    # (change requires restart)

# -Connection to up stream servers -

trusted_servers = ''
                                    # trusted server list which are used
                                    # to confirm network connection
                                    # (hostA,hostB,hostC,...)
                                    # (change requires restart)
ping_path = '/bin'
                                    # ping command path
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Watchdog communication Settings -

wd_hostname = '192.168.1.13'
                                    # Host name or IP address of this watchdog
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_port = 9000
                                    # port number for watchdog service
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_authkey = ''
                                    # Authentication key for watchdog communication
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Virtual IP control Setting -

delegate_IP = '192.168.1.100'
                                    # delegate IP address
                                    # If this is empty, virtual IP never bring up.
                                    # (change requires restart)
ifconfig_path = '/sbin'
                                    # ifconfig command path
                                    # (change requires restart)
if_up_cmd = 'ifconfig eth1:0 inet 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.255'

if_down_cmd = 'ifconfig eth1:0 down'
                                    # shutdown delegate IP command
                                    # (change requires restart)

arping_path = '/usr/sbin'           # arping command path
                                    # (change requires restart)

arping_cmd = 'arping -U $_IP_$ -w 1'
                                    # arping command
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Behaivor on escalation Setting -

clear_memqcache_on_escalation = on
                                    # Clear all the query cache on shared memory
                                    # when standby pgpool escalate to active pgpool
                                    # (= virtual IP holder).
                                    # This should be off if client connects to pgpool
                                    # not using virtual IP.
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_escalation_command = ''
                                    # Executes this command at escalation on new active pgpool.
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Lifecheck Setting -


# - Lifecheck Setting -

# -- common --

wd_lifecheck_method = 'heartbeat'
                                    # Method of watchdog lifecheck ('heartbeat' or 'query')
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_interval = 3
                                    # lifecheck interval (sec) > 0
                                    # (change requires restart)

# -- heartbeat mode --

wd_heartbeat_port = 9694
                                    # Port number for receiving heartbeat signal
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_heartbeat_keepalive = 2
                                    # Interval time of sending heartbeat signal (sec)
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_heartbeat_deadtime = 30
                                    # Deadtime interval for heartbeat signal (sec)
                                    # (change requires restart)
heartbeat_destination0 = '172.23.0.23'
                                    # Host name or IP address of destination 0
                                    # for sending heartbeat signal.
                                    # (change requires restart)
heartbeat_destination_port0 = 9694
                                    # Port number of destination 0 for sending
                                    # heartbeat signal. Usually this is the
                                    # same as wd_heartbeat_port.
                                    # (change requires restart)
heartbeat_device0 = 'eth1'

# -- query mode --

wd_life_point = 3
                                    # lifecheck retry times
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_query = 'SELECT 1'
                                    # lifecheck query to pgpool from watchdog
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_dbname = 'template1'
                                    # Database name connected for lifecheck
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_user = 'nobody'
                                    # watchdog user monitoring pgpools in lifecheck
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_password = ''
                                    # Password for watchdog user in lifecheck
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Other pgpool Connection Settings -

other_pgpool_hostname0 = '172.23.0.23'
                                    # Host name or IP address to connect to for other pgpool 0
                                    # (change requires restart)
other_pgpool_port0 = 9999
                                    # Port number for othet pgpool 0
                                    # (change requires restart)
other_wd_port0 = 9000
                                    # Port number for othet watchdog 0
                                    # (change requires restart)
```

If you need more information only let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactely the same problem.
i resolve some ones but i already have others

i proceed like this:

```
mkdir /home/apache
cp /sbin/ifconfig /home/apache
cp /usr/sbin/arping  /home/apache
```

next you must add the setuid bit:

```
chmod ugo+s /home/ifconfig
chmod ugo+s /home/arping
```

but i have this message:

```
[root@Fil-pgp apache]# /pgpool/bin/pgpool 
2014-10-28 15:31:33 LOG:   pid 4053: wd_chk_setuid all commands have setuid bit
2014-10-28 15:31:33 LOG:   pid 4053: watchdog might call network commands which using setuid bit.
```

any suggestion?